# Outlook meetings and auto accept/reply

Tags: outlook, calendar, auto-reply

*First, I'm not sure if this question should be here or superuser, but here it comes.*

Im trying to set up a room to auto accept meetings and so far its good but i was wondering if it's possible to change it to *"do not send respond"* when it accepts and sends some reply when it's the same time as another existing meeting, so it declined.

And a little extra question: is it possible to chance that auto reply it sends, since it's in English, and I would like to chance it to Danish and some text I choose myself?

Comment: Which Exchange Server version?

Comment: its Exchange 2007 and outlook 2010 beta

Answer (score 3):

To set all of the Room mailboxes on your Exchange 2007 server to AutoAccept any available times, you may run the following PowerShell command.

```
Get-Mailbox | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -eq "Room"} | Set-MailboxCalendarSettings -AutomateProcessing AutoAccept
```

You can use the *AddAdditionalResponse* and *AdditionalResponse* parameters to customize the response that a specific Room resource will respond with.

```
Set-MailboxCalendarSettings -Identity "Room1" -AddAdditionalResponse:$true -AddAdditionalResponse:"<font color-red> Add your response</font>"
```

You can also set the response in OWA by logging in as that Room mailbox.

Comment: In addition to this solution the change the language of the roommailbox to Danish. Which also can be done with OWA or powershell. Set-Mailbox -Identity "myroom" -Language da-dk